# 2005 Altima Shuts off while stopped, starts back up

Tags: nissan, altima

Nissan Altima shuts off while waiting at a light. While driving at above 45mph it hesitates/jerks. Engine light has turned on only once and gave error code for cylinder#2 it has since not turned on when it shuts off. Any solutions or causes as to what this may be?

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Could you post the error code and fuel trims?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675) It will help us help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Don't remember the code exactly, the employee from autozone just let me know it was a cylinder#2 misfire. Don't have a proper way of checking the fuel trim.

Comment: The trouble is that we need some direction here, else the possible issues can be quite overwhelming. Scanner tools are pretty cheap; several free apps exist for smartphones these days that just require you to invest in an ELM327 reader that you can plug into your OBD-II port